# Could PDF's `/Filespec` type allow for remote file access?

Tags: exploit, pdf

I've read [the PDF 1.7 spec 7.11.1](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (okay, not all the spec, but a part of it), and I've seen that you have what Adobe calls `/Filespec` type objects.

As far as I get it, this means that a PDF can make a reference to a local file (or even a remote file using URI scheme) when opening the PDF. This would be a pretty neat way of attacking some servers I'm in charge of, because such server accepts user-uploaded PDF, opens them with wkhtml/tcpdf/jasper to make changes in that PDF, and then resend this PDF to the user. So if the user-uploaded PDF contains a file reference to, say, `/dev/random`, and if that reference is used as the PDF's page content, then it would open up a breach to read arbitrary server's file content?

I would like to test that, but I can't make such PDF exploit: when opening the PDF I've forged on my lab (ie: not server, just a basic PDF reader), then no content is displayed (and PDF is considered broken).

So do you have some example of such PDF with a working file reference (so I can test if PDF processor is vulnerable to it)? Or any reference stating that these `/Filespec` cannot be used to read arbitrary file's content (so no need to test the PDF processor)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the feasibility of what you suspect. A library able to work with pdf files may not need to process such Filespec entry to perform its work (for instance the Filespec -if not an embedded file- could be referring to a font, only used when rendering it). And I suspect any library will not enable reading of external files without explicitly enabling such feature, as it could lead -as you note- to nasty surprises.

However, in case of doubt, and given that these are complex programs dealing with a nin-trivial format, I would apply the precautionary principle and process them in a sandbox/chroot/firejail/docker container, so *even if the programs processing the pdf could be directed to open arbitrary files* they actually can't open any sensitive file, only the standard files that were included inside the sandbox.

Comment: That's actually why I would like help forging such PDF-to-read-file: to test if the lib does handle them under the hood. Sandboxing could be a mitigation, but that means 1 sandbox must be made per application user, otherwise, user A will upload forged PDF to read files uploaded by user B (while user A should not be allowed to access user B files). Knowing that we also have business rules so user C can allow user A to access *some* of user C's files, it seems impossible to make up a proper sandbox system (would mean 1 sandbox per user-access combination, I'm not ready to make N^N sandboxes :))